# Connecting Social Auth to MongoEngine models gives errors

Tags: python, django, django-models, mongoengine, django-socialauth

After doing necessary modifications in my **settings.py** file as explained in [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/django.html) and [Social Auth](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html) documentations, I added this code finally:

```
    AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mongo_auth.MongoUser'
    SOCIAL_AUTH_MODELS = 'social_auth.db.mongoengine_models'
```

I get this error after trying to run the server:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_auth/db/mongoengine_models.py", line 35,
  in <module> class UserSocialAuth(Document, UserSocialAuthMixin):
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/social_auth/db/mongoengine_models.py", line 37, in UserSocialAuth
  user = ReferenceField(USER_MODEL, dbref=True)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/fields.py", line 837, in __init__
  self.error('Argument to ReferenceField constructor must be a '
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/base/fields.py", line 125, in error
  raise ValidationError(message, errors=errors, field_name=field_name)
  mongoengine.errors.ValidationError: Argument to ReferenceField constructor must be a
  document class or a string
```

If I remove SOCIAL_AUTH_MODELS, the server runs but Social Auth cannot work since it doesn't have any engine if MongoEngine is out of order.

MongoEngine's version: 0.8.3

I couldn't find the solution. How can I solve this?

---

**SOLUTION:**

If you look at the `social_auth.db.mongoengine_models.py`, you will see that `USER_MODEL_APP` will be set to a model, not a document. This model is defined as `mongo_auth.MongoUser`. Because ReferenceField requires a Document, not a Model (MongoUser), I had to neglect `if` statement and set `USER_MODEL` to a `User` document (mongo.django.auth.User) as it is already written in `else` statement. I removed replaced if and else statement by only those two lines:

```
USER_MODEL_MODULE, USER_MODEL_NAME = 'mongoengine.django.auth.User'.rsplit('.', 1)
USER_MODEL = getattr(import_module(USER_MODEL_MODULE), USER_MODEL_NAME)
```

Another way is removing `SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL` and `AUTH_USER_MODEL` from settings but I am not sure if MongoEngine requires `AUTH_USER_MODEL`setting. I didn't test it.

Comment: Any trouble importing `mongo_auth.MongoUser` ? Could you try doing: `print get_model('mongo_auth', 'User')`? (`get_model` is at `django.db.models`)

Comment: I added `from django.db.models import get_model
print get_model('mongo_auth', 'User')` in the end of settings.py and it returned `None`. But I successfully imported this: `print get_model('mongo_auth', 'MongoUser')` Were you trying to say that?

Comment: That's what I was trying to say, probably typed the comment to fast.

Comment: Is `mongo_auth` defined before or after `social_auth` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting?

Comment: They are both defined. `mongoengine.django.mongo_auth` and `social_auth`. Is it possible that maybe MongoEngine's current version does not match with Social Auth's structure because it is written that Social Auth was tested with 0.6.10? Maybe the methods used in classed do not match in parameters base like MongoEngine's method requires String but Social Auth passes a function? I am going really crazy here.

Comment: Thanks for your trouble @omab , I wrote my solution above. There is a mismatch between two apps since MongoEngine requires a document but Social Auth passes a model instead. Maybe it's because of my settings but sure that was the problem.